# Velocity of interaction between particles in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, velocity

We always hear in classical mechanics that the interaction between particles happens instantaneously, and I think this assumption is obvious just by seeing Newton's third law. But I was wondering, is it possible to show that the velocity of this interaction is infinitely fast, just assuming the force is dependent only on the position of the particles (my professor said it is, but I can't see how to do it).

I couldn't find about it anywhere so, if anyone could help, I'd appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: One can't show something that is not true. Newtonian mechanics is simply an approximation which relies on neglecting the speed of light and the speed of sound. We have other theories which are more precise, at the cost of being more complex.

Comment: @CuriousOne But the approximation that Newtonian mechanics does ($c \rightarrow \infty $) doesn't imply that interaction occurs instantaneously?

Comment: It only implies that Newtonian mechanics doesn't care about it. Newtonian mechanics cares about almost nothing, that's the reason why it is so "simple".

Comment: I am puzzled by this one perhaps someone can enlighten me, but if two objects collide there resultant velocities can be calculated by conservation of momentum and it can be measured to be so.But by this the resultant paths of the two collided objects is instantaneous. Now to my mind it may be lacking by my perception but what happens to force F=Ma the two objects collide and the acceleration is instantaneous which would mean the force on each object is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people say the force acting on particle 1 at some definite time depends only on positions of the other particles at the same time, this actually means there is no propagation of the interaction. The interaction is just everywhere and reflects current state of particles in the whole world. The concept of speed of interaction is superfluous.

"Infinite speed" of interaction is just a figure of speech that refers to this kind of theory.

Answer (score 0):

By Newton's third law, action and reaction happens instantaneously if they are in contact with each other or at rest (in inertial frames). But, they do not hold true if you consider two moving objects, both traversing in orthogonal directions, for example, two charged particles moving in perpendicular directions away from each other. In such a case, it can be seen that a direct application of Newton's third law on the electromagnetic action and reaction on each particle violates the conservation of momentum of the system. This simply is due to the fact that nothing, nor even action or reaction can travel faster than light. So action and reaction interactions are not infinitely speedy. We have a universal speed limit.

Two charged particles interact via electromagnetic field, which happens at the speed of light (still it's finite, not infinite). But when the distance between the charges is sufficiently large, there is some delay, and we use the concepts of retarded potentials there.

Comment: But the fact that electromagnetism tells us that this interaction happens at the speed of light is why Lorentz came up with his transformations, because Galilean's transformations didn't hold. But in classical **mechanics** there's no limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the force on a particle $B$ due to a particle $A$. The forces in newtonian physics, namely electromagnetism and gravity, have the following laws:

The acceleration of $B$ due to $A$ is

$$ \vec{a}_B = \frac{G m_A}{r_{AB}(t)^2} \hat{r}_{AB} + \frac{k q_B q_A}{m_B r_{AB}(t)^2} \hat{r}_{AB} $$

where $r_{AB}(t)$ is the distance between $A$ and $B$ at universal time slice $t$.

Therefore, the force on $B$ due to $A$ depends only on the state of $A$ at the "exact same time." You could imagine a force law that that propagated with finite speed by considering a force that depends on the position, or whatever other state variables, of $A$ at some time before $t$, $t'$, where $t' = t - \frac{r_{AB}}{c}$ for a force that propagates at velocity $c$.

Indeed, following this line of logic brings us to special relativity.